# Reference request - maximum conservative extension of a probability assignment

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory

I made up some definitions which probably lead to some interesting mathematics. However, I suspect they've studied before.  So that I don't end up reinventing the wheel (always bad!), I'm after a reference recommendation.

In what follows, $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the powerset of $\Omega$.

**Defn 1**. For all sets $\Omega$, define that a *probability assignment* on $\Omega$ is a function $f : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ for some $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. Note that $\mathcal{F}$ needn't be a sigma algebra.

Note that a *probability measure* is a kind of probability assignment, in which case $\mathcal{F}$ *will* be a sigma algebra.

**Defn 2**. Given two probability assignments on a set $\Omega$, call them $f : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and $g : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, say that $f$ is *extended* by $g$ iff $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, and for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds that $f(A)=g(A)$.

**Defn 3**. Define that a probability assignment $f$ on a set $\Omega$ is *consistent* iff there exists a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$ such that $f$ is extended by $\mathbb{P}$.

**Defn 4**. Given a consistent probability assignment $f$ on a set $\Omega$ and a (not necessarily consistent) probability assignment $g$ on $\Omega$, define that $f$ is *conservatively* extended by $g$ iff for all probability measures $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$ such that $f$ is extended by $\mathbb{P}$, it holds that $g$ is also extended by $\mathbb{P}$.

**Defn 5**. For all consistent probability assignments $f$ on a set $\Omega$, define that the *maximum conservative extension* of $f$ is the unique conservative extension $g$ on $\Omega$ such that no proper extension of $g$ is a conservative extension of $g$.

A couple of questions that interest me: If $f : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a consistent probability assignment and $g : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is the maximum conservative extension of $f$, what conditions will $\mathcal{G}$ necessarily satisfy? Under what circumstances will $\mathcal{G}$ be a sigma algebra? And if $\mathcal{G}$ is indeed a sigma algebra, does this imply that $g$ is a probability measure?

All potential leads are welcome.

On the other hand, if you suspect that the references I'm looking for may not exist, please say so.

Comment: You have not defined many of the terms. Examples: Is $\mathcal{F}$ a sigma field, and if so what kind of sigma field? What is $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$? etc...

Comment: @Learner. No, $\mathcal{F}$ needn't be a sigma field. And $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the powerset of $\Omega$.